# RegExp how to detect and insert a string in ` for loop`

Tags: javascript, html, regex, for-loop

I am working on a `little plugin` that detects if `for loop` is **running long or not**,if not then it run the loop and when the `limit is exceed` then it `stops` the loop.

So i Insert a function inside a loop named `timeout()`

Like :

```
 UserCode = 'for(i=0;timeout() && i<=50000;i++){for(j=0;timeout() && j<5000;j++){$("#ps").append("hey I am a bug<br>");}}'

 eval(UserCode);
```

So,here I insert `timeout()` Manually,but this is inserted by my plugin,that detect the for loop and insert at right place,because I am not so Good in `RegExp` so I need your suggestions that how i perform this task ?

After Insertion i create the string of whole code, and append it to `<script>` tag;
So then it will run their!

And my `timeout()` functions that perform its own operation to stop long running loop.

```
 var outLimit = 10000;
 function timeout(){
   if(outLimit){
    outLimit = outLimit - 1;
   }
   else{

    alert('TimeOut-Long Script Detected !!!');
   }

 return outLimit;
}
```

Give me an Idea How would i achieve this and put my function at right place ?

[**My Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ashish41191/ywvL8/2/)

Comment: how is that even related to regex ?

Comment: tags should be used appropriately

Comment: because the code that i have is `user code` and it is a string and i want to apply regex in it..@Amit

Comment: Its only with the help of regExp, I want to detect the  for loop that is inside string @Amit

Comment: Ok, but it doesn't apply here

Comment: But why let me Explain ?@Amit

Comment: Its a example,The Whole code that i have in Example is a string so now  tell me why am not able to apply regexp in my string that containing code?@Amit

Comment: You want to profile code at "how long is this for-loop` and break if it is too long?

Comment: First, I understand what you need but, regex is for matching strings. I don't think you can match js code. unless it is a string

Comment: Ohk Wait i update it @Amit

Comment: please do so ! Waiting to answer :)

Comment: @Amit Please check,i update it..And check my fiddle also

Comment: Yeah, now it makes sense

Comment: do you want to insert `timeout()` after `i` and `j` ?

Comment: yes,, same as above,,after i;and before j with `&&` operator!@Amit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
/for\(\w+=\d;/g
```

and replace it with:

```
$&timeout()
```

<strike>A jsfiddle is on its way.</strike>

Just use the above like this:

```
var UserCode = 'for(i=0; && i<=50000;i++){for(j=0; && j<5000;j++){$("#ps").append("hey I am a bug<br>");}}'
    UserCode = UserCode.replace(/for\(\w+=\d;/g, '$&timeout()');
    eval(UserCode);
```

## JsFiddle

<kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/v29Rv/</kbd>

Comment: Am i Ask a personal Question ?@Amit

Comment: Of course it is @AshishMishra it is my fb profile pic

Comment: So ,it seems that you are a very little boy ? is it right ?@Amit

Comment: Amazing yarr...Keep it up !! I like to meet you !! :) @Amit

Comment: @AshishMishra come to this chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49243/discussion-between-ashish-mishra-and-amit-joki